# How can I make my batch file easier to exit from a user input?

Tags: batch-file

My problem is that I believe I overengineered a solution to have the user either input a Y/y or an N/n to either open the destination folder or exit the code. I am looking for any ideas that could reduce the complexity while still remaining function as its current requirements. Here is what I have so far:

```
:end
echo The program has finished the installation. Do you want to navigate to the destination folder?
echo If you select no the program will exit.
echo.
set /p check=Enter Y or y to enter the destination folder. Enter N or n to leave the program. 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "delims=YyNn" %%a in ("!check!") do set "check="
endlocal & set "check=%check%"
if not defined check (
        echo Please enter either a Y/y or N/n as a response. && echo. && echo Press any key to retry... && pause >nul && cls
        goto end
)
if %check%==Y (explorer "%file_path%") & pause >nul
if %check%==y (explorer "%file_path%") & pause >nul
if %check%==N (exit)
if %check%==n (exit)
```

This code does work correctly but I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish the same output. I included a limiter so that it is guaranteed to work with only a y or n, regardless of capitalization. File_path is just the directory on the computer where the previous commands downloaded a file after a conversion process.

Comment: The `IF` command has the `/I` option for case insensitive compare. But better would be to use the `CHOICE` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a better way? yes:

```
:end
choice /m "Installation complete! Do you want to navigate to the destination folder?"
if %errorlevel% neq 2 start "" explorer "%file_path%"
```

really simple. `y/n` is default `choice` output. `choice` also does not care about case so it will accept `YyNn` and it also does not require the <kbd>enter</kbd> key to be pressed after key selection. Then bonus is that there is no need for the additional `echo` command as it can form part of `choice`'s `/m`essage format.

`%errorlevel%` of `2` in this case would be `N` was pressed. If the condition was not met (someone pressed yes where `%errorlevel%` is `1`) then we skip opening `explorer` and you're done.

if this is really the end of the script, it will fall through and exit (if double clicked and no `pause`) if not really the end of the script, then just add `exit` below the `if %errorlevel%` line.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing too much, you could reduce it to these four lines:

```sh
:end
Echo The program has finished the installation.
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C YN /N /M "Enter N to Exit or Y to navigate to the destination directory."
If Not ErrorLevel 2 Start "" "%file_path%"
```

As you specifically wanted the `Y`|`N` entries you should use the `/C` option, as the defaults without it are locale/language specific.